# How to align views inside HStack according to view in VStack?

Tags: swiftui, vstack, hstack

Let's say we have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.black
                .frame(width: 130, height: 30)
            
            HStack(spacing: 17) {
                ChildView()
                
                ChildView()
                
                ChildView()
                
                ChildView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 2) {
            Color.red
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            
            Text("Title")
                .font(.system(size: 10))
        }
    }
}
```

actual result is:
[image]

I want to stretch my `HStack` so that the first `ChildView` is aligned to the left edge of the red square and black rectangle, and the last one is aligned to the right edge of the red square and black rectangle. Like this:
[image]

I'm guessing it's possible to make a layout like this using custom alignmentGuide, but i'm stuck on it.

Comment: Yep. See [SwiftUI Labs](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this layout with the following changes to the code:

1. Apply the constraining width to the `VStack` containing the black color and the `HStack` and apply `maxWidth: .infinity` to the black color.
2. Set the spacing for the `HStack` to 0.
3. Add a `Spacer` between each of the items in the `HStack`.
4. Use a hidden placeholder to reserve vertical space for the labels.
5. Show the actual labels as an overlay, so that they do not impact the layout.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.black
                .frame(height: 30)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ChildView()
                Spacer()
                ChildView()
                Spacer()
                ChildView()
                Spacer()
                ChildView()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 130)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 2) {
            Color.red
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            Text(".").hidden()
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text("Title")
                .fixedSize()
        }
        .font(.system(size: 10))
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]